# How to compose valid token depending on pre-defined macros (C++ preprocessor)?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose some tokens `FOO`, `BAR`, and `DUD` (and possibly more) are `#defined` or not. I would like to have a macro `EXTEND(name)` that generates a valid extended name, e.g.

```
#define FOO
#undef  BAR
#define DUD
EXTEND(object)
```

expands to

```
object_foo_dud
```

Is it possible to write macro `EXTEND` with less than O(2<sup>n</sup>) lines if there are `n` macro tokens (like `FOO`, `BAR`, and `DUD`)? I think it should be possible with O(n) lines, but how?

I've **tried this**:

```
#ifdef FOO
#  define ExtFOO(name) name ## _foo
#else
#  define ExtFOO(name) name
#endif

#ifdef BAR
#  define ExtBAR(name) ExtFOO(name) ## _bar
#else
#  define ExtBAR(name) ExtFOO(name)
#endif

#ifdef DUD
#  define ExtDUD(name) ExtBAR(name) ## _dud
#else
#  define ExtDUD(name) ExtBAR(name)
#endif

#define EXTEND(name) ExtDUD(name)
```

but

> test.cc:26:5: error: pasting formed ')_dud', an invalid preprocessing token
>           EXTEND(object)
>           ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `##` operator concatenates two preprocessing tokens and must yield a *single* valid token. For example, from section 6.10.3.3 of the C99 spec:

> For both object-like and function-like macro invocations, before the replacement list is
>   reexamined for more macro names to replace, each instance of a `##` preprocessing token
>   in the replacement list (not from an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing
>   token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token. Placemarker preprocessing tokens are handled specially: concatenation of two placemarkers results in a single placemarker preprocessing token, and concatenation of a placemarker with a non-placemarker preprocessing token results in the non-placemarker preprocessing token. **If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.** The resulting token is available for further macro replacement. The order of evaluation of `##` operators is unspecified.

So the expansion `ExtBAR(name) ## _dud` is invalid since it would yield `ExtBAR(object)_dud`.

I'd go with the following approach:

```
#ifdef FOO
#  define ValFOO _foo
#else
#  define ValFOO
#endif

#ifdef BAR
#  define ValBAR _bar
#else
#  define ValBAR
#endif

#ifdef DUD
#  define ValDUD _dud
#else
#  define ValDUD
#endif

#define CONCAT(a, b, c, d) a ## b ## c ## d
#define XCONCAT(a, b, c, d) CONCAT(a, b, c, d)
#define EXTEND(name) XCONCAT(name, ValFOO, ValBAR, ValDUD)
```

The intermediate `XCONCAT` step is needed because macro arguments are not expanded if they're concatenated using `##`.